# pom.xml is not able to read pom.properties file in maven

Tags: java, maven

I want to move properties like version and other properties to pom.properties file.
I have already tried with **properties-maven-plugin** but still not getting any success.Please let me know how can i achieve this.

```
<build>
<plugins>
                <!-- Maven clean plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <files>
                                    <file>pom.properties</file>
                                </files>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>....
```

Here is my pom.properties file data..

```
appserver.home=D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.64
central=http://192.168.0.110:9999/repository/internal/
snapshot=http://192.168.0.110:9999/repository/stablesnapshots/
spring.version=4.0.5.RELEASE
hibernate.version=4.3.5.Final
log4j.version=1.2.17
jdk.version=1.7
context.path=Evoke
cxf.rt.frontend.jaxrs.version=3.0.0
cxf.bundle.version=2.7.10
cxf.bundle.minimal.version=2.7.10
javax.ws.rs.api.version=2.0-m10
commons.httpclient.version=3.1
jackson.version=2.0.1
jersey.multipart.version=1.18
spring.security.version=3.2.7.RELEASE
drools.version=6.2.0.Final
itext.version=4.2.0
quartz.version=2.2.1
```

Comment: Run it with -X or -e parameter and add here the stacktrace of the problem

Comment: You should show us the project structure too

Comment: To be perfectly honest, if you do this, use Ant and not Maven. You are breaking the convention.

Comment: Why would you want to move the file? @Michael-O is right, this is not what you use Maven for.

Comment: So you all are saying i should not move the properties file.Then why do we have a default pom.properties file and whats wrong  i want to isolate properties from pom.xml to pom.properties file.It will be help if i can get little more details on this

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>initialize</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <files>
              <file>pom.properties</file>
            </files>
            <outputFile>out.properties</outputFile>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
```

It should do the trick. Goals are executed in the order they are declared.

### Update based on comments

The problem with having an external file to hold the versions of your dependencies is that when you install or deploy your artifact, the POM will look like this in repository, if it was possible:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

When someone else tries to depend on this POM, how does he or she know what `${spring.version}` resolves to? The answer is in the external file, which is embedded - if we are lucky - in the artifact (jar file). And to find the artifact in the repository, you need to know  `${spring.version}` so it becomes a catch-22 problem.

Now, having said this, Maven has its own mechanism for doing this:

`<dependencyManagement>` and `<properties>`:

### DependencyManagement

```
...
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
...
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <!-- No need to specify version, it is inferred from the section above -->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

### Properties

```
<properties>
  <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
...
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- spring.version can be reused, because Maven properties behave like constants -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The good thing is, if you you declare your versions in the `<dependencyManagement>` section, you can create a POM with only these type of entries in it, and have other POMs import the versions from that POM. This webpage describes how it works: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies

Since POMs always should be version controlled, you get all the added benefits from it: traceability, dependency control, portable builds, etc.

Comment: It is not working,not able to find pom.properties.I am getting error:-                                                                                                       [ERROR]Some problems were encountered while processing thePOMs:
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-orm:jar must be a valid version but is '${spring.version}'. @ line 182, column 13

Comment: You have failed to tell us _why_ you need this. Initially, we thought you were just trying to read a properties file, but it turns out that you want the contents of your `pom.properties` file to participate in dependency resolution. AFAIK, it cannot be done using this approach. Even if you execute the plugin during the `validate` phase, which is the first phase, dependency resolution occurs before that (and it has to) so `${spring.version}` cannot be resolved at this stage. Using resource filtering and the `ant-run` plugin might suit your needs better.

Comment: I tried using ant-run plugin, but i am not able to resolve this.can u plz help in little more details

Comment: Sure. Exactly what do you want the `ant-run` plugin to do?

Comment: I just want to write my dependency versions in pom.properties file, so that when i build project pom.xml should read dependency versions from pom.properties file.

Comment: I was afraid of that... :-) This is a really bad practice. You are trying to circumvent one of Maven's tenets and it's a dead end I'm afraid. There are other mechanisms supported by Maven that achieve this, but they do not involve external files. I am willing to continue this discussion in chat, if you are interested.

Comment: Yes i would like to know why this is bad practice.What can be the problem.I would request you to help me in this and solve my issue and thanks for all your help